# Run a function inside Express route and still render page in sendFile

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, express

I have a React app using server-side rendering and I'm trying to hit a route using middleware to check assign redirects.

```
const app = express();

...

app.use("/", redirectRouter);
app.use("/widgets", widgetRouter);
app.use("/api", apiRouter);

app.use((req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public", "index.html"));
});
```

The second two middlewares are for some backend purposes and the last `app.use` serves up the React app if no other route is found. `app.use("/", redirectRouter)` is where I'm trying to run a loop that assigns redirects to an array of URLs. I want express to hit the middleware, run, but still serve `index.html` at the bottom.

Currently `app.use("/", redirectRouter)` does nothing. I've tried changing `"/"` to `"*"` which hits the route but no longer renders the page. I've also tried variations of `app.get`, `app.all`, and `app.options` which also do nothing.

EDIT: Forgot to add that this is inside the `redirectRouter`

```
redirectRouter.get("*", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  // my function
});
```

But the problems are the same... `"*"` hangs up the app and `"/"` does nothing.

Comment: protip: never use `sendFile` if you're not sending actual binary file responses. Use a render engine and render a proper response. Also don't send your index.html response as an `app.use`, that's 100% an `app.get`. Or if it's truly static content, use [express.static](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) of course. (And don't serve your index.html as a 404, just send a proper 404 page)

Comment: To help you with why `redirectRouter.get()` hangs, we need to see ALL of its code.  Please add that to your question.